# Spyder is not recognised as an internal command

Tags: python, pip, spyder, intel-python

I have downloaded the new [IntelPython](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python) and installed the package according to the directions on the page.

So, after I installed the application, I followed these instructions for Windows:

1. Open a terminal or shell and then navigate to the installation
   folder. This will normally be C:\IntelPython3. Navigate to the
   Scripts folder, and run activate.
2. After the script activates the
   root Python environment, Intel Distribution for Python is ready to
   use.

All good so far, then when I activated the `root` environment I started installing packages with `pip`, keras, tensorflow etc. 
Amongst the packages I installed spyder too.

The issue is that when I am on the environment `root` I can type python and I start python 3.6 normally where then I can `import` all the packages that I installed. 
But, when in the command window (while I am in the root env) I type spyder nothing happens. Instead I get a message that

> Spyder is not recognised as an internal command

[image]
If I type, within C:\IntelPython3, `conda list` then I can see spyder but as I said the command doesn't work. I tried to find the `spyder.exe` within the C:\IntelPython3\Scripts folder but there is not there.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks

**Edit:** I can start Jupyter Notebook too from Windows terminal, the only issue is Spyder which is weird.

[image]

Comment: Could you try to reinstall `spyder` with `conda`?

Comment: It seems you installed Spyder with `pip` instead of using `conda` (which is a bad practice and you should avoid it). The problem is with `pip` you need to start Spyder with `spyder3` instead of `spyder`.

Comment: I will uninstall spyder then and try to install the package with coda instead. By the way, I tried calling spyder3, but nothing happens. Literally nothing. I get back to C:\IntelPython3>

Comment: Also, when you say bad practice you mean only for spyder? Or in general I should prefer coda? Because most of the packages I use recommend pip instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Jespar, As you are using a specific distribution of python based on anaconda that uses some optimized packages, you should stick with conda when you can.

Comment: Yep, guys you were right. With conda it worked perfectly.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba why is it bad practice? managing environments with anaconda is a nightmare - I've run into problems like anaconda refusing to create environments. I prefer using pyenv and venv but want a good IDE like spyder so I prefer to not install conda. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Conda and pip packages can't be mixed because they are binary incompatible. So if you want to use conda to install Spyder, you have to use conda to manage tour envs, Else you'll find weird segfaults, DLL issues and all kinds of errors along the way (StackOverflow is full of them).

Comment: Yep I agree with you but if I've never used Anaconda and I've set up my python using pyenv, then of course there is no option but to use pip to install Spyder. https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html